# What dependency to add in maven pom for using powermock with mockito1?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

Powermockito [doc](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-Maven) shows the below dependency to add in a pom.

```
<properties>
    <powermock.version>2.0.2</powermock.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But there is no `powermock-api-mockito` with version 2.0.2. As per the [supported versions](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#supported-versions) powermockito 2.0 is supposed to work with mockito 1.10.x.

Can someone let me know what dependency I have to add in maven pom for powermock 2 to work with the latest Mockito1 version (1.10.19)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/1019).

Reposting the relevant answer here

> This still needs to be changed. documentation is accurate under the
> supported versions further in the mockito support docs here:
>
> https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions
> So 2.0.2 needs to be changed to 1.7.4 for mockito1. at the top of the
> docs where you can find the pom configuration, it is noted that
> powermock2 does not support mockito1. Please change this.